# F# casting an object to an interface

Tags: interface, f#

I have a class called 'Pane' (think glass pane) that implements IPane:

```
type IPane =
    abstract PaneNumber : int with get, set
    abstract Thickness : float<m> with get, set
    abstract ComponentNumber : int with get, set
    abstract Spectra : IGlassDataValues with get, set
    ...

type Pane(paneNumber, componentNumber, spectra, ...) =
    let mutable p = paneNumber
    let mutable n = componentNumber
    let mutable s = spectra
    ...

    interface IPane with
        member this.PaneNumber
            with get() = p
            and set(value) = p <- value
        member this.ComponentNumber
            with get() = n
            and set(value) = n <- value
        member this.Spectra
            with get() = s
            and set(value) = s <- value
            ...
```

I create a list of panes (Pane list):

```
let p = [ p1; p2 ]
```

however I need to cast this to an IPane list as this is a parameter type in another function. The following code produces an error:

```
let p = [ p1; p2 ] :> IPane list
'Type constraint mismatch. The type
  Pane list
is not compatible with type
  IPane list
The type 'IPane' does not match the type 'Pane'
```

This is confusing as Pane implements IPane. Simply passing the Pane list object as a parameter into the required function also produces an error.

How do I cast Pane list to IPane list?

Comment: Small suggestion for future questions, almost all the code here is irrelevant, a simple repro is `type t() = class end; type q() = inherit t();let f (a:t list)=();f[q();q()]`

Comment: Thanks, to be honest I sometimes find it useful to have a bit of context to understand what the user is trying to do but I will take your point on board.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

F# doesn't allow inheritence in quite the way you want.

A better way would be to use:

```
[p1 ;p2] |> List.map (fun x -> x:> IPane)
```

Alternatively, you can change your function to use something like this

```
let f (t:#IPane list) = ()
```

and here you can do `f [p1;p2]` as the `#` tells the compiler that any type that inherits from `IPane` is fine.

Answer (score 4):

Another way would have been like this:

```
let p = [p1; p2] : IPane list
// or equivalently
let p : IPane list = [p1; p2]
```

In your original code, what happened is that first it inferred the type of `[p1; p2]` without any constraints, which it found to be `Pane list`, and then it tried to upcast it to `IPane list`, which it couldn't do because F# has strict variance rules: even if `Pane` is a subtype of `IPane`, `Pane list` is not a subtype of `IPane list`.

In my code above, on the other hand, instead of trying to infer the type of `[p1; p2]`, it verifies that it can match the type `IPane list` that it was given; and in doing so, it implicitly upcast the individual list elements `p1` and `p2` to `IPane`.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was easier than I thought.

I was defining p1 and p2 as:

```
let p1 = new Pane(1, 2, blah, blah)
let p2 = new Pane(2, 2, blah, blah)
```

However if I cast them as IPanes at this point, everything works:

```
let p1 = new Pane(1, 2, blah, blah) :> IPane
let p2 = new Pane(2, 2, blah, blah) :> IPane
```

John Palmer's solution above is probably more rigorous as the original pane objects are maintained as the concrete types.